# Stripping password from $request_body POST nginx logs

Tags: nginx, logging, openresty

I am trying to strip password from my nginx/openresty POST data logs.

Post data logs looks like this

```
 "POST /myapi/login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 37 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
```

Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36" 0.000
 req_body:"----password\x22\x0D\x0A\x0D\x0Atestuser\x0D\x0A------9\x0D\x0AContent-Disposition: form-data; 
 resp_body:"{success: \x22login succesful\x22}\x0A" upstream_response_time=- msec=1562036599.391 upstream_connect_time=- request_time=0.000 status=200

Here I want to replace "testuser" with "XXXXX" so that the user password is not visible to anyone

Comment: But why are you logging POST data? It's not a good thing to do

Comment: @TarunLalwani its part of my requirement as in our target application we don't have capability/we don't want to log the request data